# @Conditionalonexpression on a class object getter

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I was wondering if there is a way to enable a class using @conditionalonexpression during runtime by evaluating an object of a class which gets its value at runtime.

FOr example:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression(#{propertyobject.getexenabled()})
class ex1{

}
```

propertyobject instance is filled with value at runtime(Say at the beginning of the program)
Is this possible to be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but `getexenabled()` method should be static.

Like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So44456388Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So44456388Application.class, args);
    }

    public static class Evaluator {
        public static boolean getexenabled() {
            //your logic here
            return true /*false*/;
        }
    }

    @Component
    @ConditionalOnExpression("#{T(com.stackoverflow.so44456388.So44456388Application$Evaluator).getexenabled()}")
    public static class RichBean {
        @PostConstruct
        private void init() {
            System.out.println("RichBean");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @bohdan. I tried it and anwyay got an exception: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on So44456388Application.  In my project the Evaluator class(The class where value would be read from)  is in a separate file. Not as nested class. Would that be a problem ? Or basially what this exception would mean here?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, you have to specify full class name for `T()` to work. Like `#{T(com.mypackage.MyEvaluator).getexenabled()}` not just `#{T(MyEvaluator).getexenabled()}`.

Comment: THANKS Boahdan. I removed the $ before class name and it worked.

Comment: @DeepakSelvakumar No problem :)

Comment: Remove the $ from your answer so that it will be perfect answer for everybody who has this problem.

Comment: Can you also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462763/ordering-evaluation-of-conditional-annotations-in-spring

Comment: Well If somebody copy paste that snippet as is, it should work. If I remove $ it will stop working since 'Evaluator' is a nested class. It didn't work for you only because you have it in separate file.