# Using hostname in ConditionalOnProperty annotation

Tags: java, spring

We have an `@Scheduled` process that does a status check. But since it runs on an array of servers and provides the same information for each, we are getting 5 redundant messages.

To fix this, I found `@ConditionalOnProperty` which works great on my dev box with my host name hard-coded for the `havingValue` property and setting a `statusHost` property in the `application-dev.yml`. This seems like a great setup since it runs when they match and doesn't when they don't. Also has the advantage that if the yml does not have the property it doesn't run on any server for that environment.

So it looks something like this in the code:

```
@Component
@ConditionOnProperty(prefix="status.", value="host", havingValue="my-dev-box")
public class StatusChecker {}
```

And the yml:

```
status:
  host: my-dev-box
```

Unfortunately, when I went to clean things up and put in the right stuff, I realized that `havingValue` needs a constant and I am, of course, dynamically finding the hostname of the server.

```
@ConditionOnProperty(prefix="status.", value="host", havingValue=System.getProperty("hostName")  // property set elsewhere
```

So my question is whether anyone has a workaround for this? It does not have to be using `@ConditionalOnProperty`, although I like that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [@Conditional with a custom Condition](https://www.romaniancoder.com/spring-conditional-bean-configuration-load-beans-based-on-custom-conditions/). Or at the beginning of your @Scheduled method you could have an if statement that checks the hostname (e.g. using  InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()) against the value you are looking for.

Comment: Ryan, that sounds good, but do you have an example of using a bean in that annotation?  All the examples I am finding are just using properties.

Comment: There is this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456388/conditionalonexpression-on-a-class-object-getter?noredirect=1&lq=1 but it does seem to be an unusual case. Presumably the use of static is related to the order of loading. I should update the answer as I am not sure if it's as smooth as I'd thought it would be. I imagine the loading order is important but it might be fine in your case to use an expression tied to bean like in 2.6 in http://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language

Comment: Actually a custom condition looks a better way - https://www.romaniancoder.com/spring-conditional-bean-configuration-load-beans-based-on-custom-conditions/

Comment: Agreed, the custom one looks a lot cleaner.  It took a minute for me to figure out where the property was, but this works great.  Thanks for your help.